# angular: directive transform value of form control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I want to transform slug control when user types in the name control.
I am applying transformations like changing spaces to hyphens(-), etc.

I created a directive for this which works partially. It does transform the value for slug input field but it doesn't change the value for slug form control when typing on name.

Here is live code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slug-transform

Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: "[formControlName][appSlugTransform]"
})
export class SlugTransformDirective {
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener("ngModelChange", ["$event"])
  onModelChange(event) {
    let newVal = this.transform(event);
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }

  transform(value) {
    let text = value.toLowerCase();
    if (text.charAt(0) == " ") {
      text = text.trim();
    }
    if (text.charAt(text.length - 1) == "-") {
      //text = (text.replace(/-/g, ""));
    }
    text = text.replace(/ +/g, "-");
    text = text.replace(/--/g, "-");
    text = text.normalize("NFKD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""); // Note: Normalize('NFKD') used to normalize special alphabets like óã to oa
    text = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "");

    return text;
  }
}
```

In the example you can see:

- If you type in the `name` input field, slug gets transformed in its input field but its form control value does not transform.
- When you type in the `slug` input field then it works correctly i.e both field and control value get transformed.

Comment: you forgot to add the directive to the input(name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally solved the issue and the magic goes here

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.valueSubscription = this.ngControl.control.valueChanges.subscribe(
    value => {
      const newVal = this.transform(value);
      this.ngControl.control.setValue(newVal, { emitEvent: false });
    }
  );
}
```

I am using `valueChanges` instead of HostListener to listen to value change.

And to update value I am now using `setValue` method of control.

Here is the running code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slug-directive

Comment: This worked for me after trying a load of different approaches (i was trying to convert string value to `number`). After this worked I tried again with `HostListener`, but this time with `emitEvent: false`. Seems that was the crucial part! Now it works with HostListener or a subscription based approach. Upvoted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the Directive to the Name FormControl,
2. Get the Control Container in the Directive
3. Get the Slug's control and patchValue to it.
4. Remove the `("name").onValueChanges()` since the directive will handle it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slug-transform-zbkdwv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal)` is not triggering the model update. Not exactly sure why that's the case but here's an alternative approach you can use with `ElementRef` & `dispatchEvent` to trigger model update:

First update the value of input using ElementRef & then use `dispatchEvent`.

```
this.el.value = newVal;
this.el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slug-transform-sdmeto

**Full updated directive:**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: "[formControlName][appSlugTransform]"
})
export class SlugTransformDirective implements OnInit {
  private el: any;

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.value = this.transform(this.el.value);
  }

  @HostListener("ngModelChange", [ "$event"])
  onNgModelChange(event) {
    let newVal = this.transform(event);
    // this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
    this.el.value = newVal;
    this.el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
  }

  transform(value) {
    let text = value.toLowerCase();
    if (text.charAt(0) == " ") {
      text = text.trim();
    }
    if (text.charAt(text.length - 1) == "-") {
      //text = (text.replace(/-/g, ""));
    }
    text = text.replace(/ +/g, "-");
    text = text.replace(/--/g, "-");
    text = text.normalize("NFKD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""); // Note: Normalize('NFKD') used to normalize special alphabets like óã to oa
    text = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "");

    return text;
  }
}
```

---

Another approach that you can try is to use `patchValue` instead of `writeValue` like this:

```
this.ngControl.control.patchValue(newVal);
```

That should trigger model change. (not tested)

Comment: it works but if you check onNgModelChange, it triggers more then 40 times for a single change

Comment: @VarunSukheja Ok i just saw that and seems like it's going into recursion here. I would suggest you to reconsider your approach because even in your implementation, it'll go into recursion if that works. 

Depending on your usecase, consider using pipe for transforming the value.

P.S. would appreciate an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: How about using blur instead of ngModelChange?